# What is the fastest way to remove all instances of a particular entry from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Suppose you have a list that is *n* entries long.  This list does not contain uniform data (some entries maybe strings, others integers, or even other lists). Assuming that list contains at least one instance of a given value, what is the fastest to remove all instances in that list?

I can think of two, a list comprehension, or `.remove()`

1. `[item for item in lst if item != itemToExclude]`
2. `for i in range(lst.count(itemToExclude)): lst.remove(itemToExclude)`

But I have no sense for which of these will be fastest for an arbitrarily large list, or if there are any other ways.  As a side note, if someone could provide some guidelines for determining the speed of methods at a glance, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

Comment: Your first method is faster no doubt.  List comprehensions are always faster than for-loops.

Comment: The first is also very likely to be faster because deleting an element from the middle of a list requires all following elements to be shifted one position to the left, repeatedly. Odds are creating a partial copy of the list will only involve very few resizes.

Comment: Can someone tell me how you call the first construct? Is there a term for it?

Comment: The first is a list comprehension.  You may or may not be better off with a generator expression, which uses ()'s instead of []'s.  List comprehensions are eager, generator expressions are lazy.

Comment: A loop around list_.remove() yields O(n^2).  The list comprehension is O(n).  Asymptotically speaking, the list comprehension should be much faster for large n, even if the for loop happened to be faster for small n - but I doubt it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `1.` will be faster in general because it iterates the list just once, in C code.  The second method iterates through the list for the `lst.count` call firstly, and iterates from the start again *every* time `lst.remove` gets called!

To measure these things, use [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

It is also worth mentioning that the two methods you propose are doing slightly different things:

```
[item for item in lst if item != itemToExclude]
```

This creates a new list.

```
for i in range(lst.count(itemToExclude)): lst.remove(itemToExclude)
```

This modifies the existing list.

Comment: "because it traverses the list just once" is not necessarily the whole story. There's at least two more factors that make the second one slow.

Comment: OK I'll change that wording

Comment: Good on you foe noting the difference between the two, I hadn't even thought of that. But what other alternatives are there?

Comment: But why do you need another alternative?  Using the list comprehension is the one obvious way to do it.

Comment: Just curiosity. I thought maybe there would be something like .remove() that would do it in one go

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution is much less efficient than your first.  `count` and `remove` both traverse the list, so to remove N copies of an item, you have to traverse the list N+1 times.  Whereas the list comprehension only traverses the list once no matter how many copies there are.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
filter(lambda x: x != itemToExclude, lst)
```

There are no Python-level loops here - the loop, going once over the data, is done "at C speed" (well, in CPython, "the usual" implementation).

Comment: This is especially fast in Python 3 ;-)

Comment: Shame about introducing the `lambda` though. If the `itemToExclude` supports `__ne__` then we can use that as part of the `filter`, otherwise, if it supports a `__eq__` then possibly `list(ifilterfalse(...))` - otherwise, a `partial(ne(...))` utilising `functools` and `operator` to make the best of `filter`

Comment: @SteveJessop Yup - extremely fast in 3.x, but not very useful if one's expecting a sequence back :)

Comment: The question was tagged `python-2.7`, so Python 3 discussions are off topic ;-)

Comment: Btw I think the performance costs of lambdas are exaggerated to the point where some people seem afraid of them. But then the question is "what's the fastest way", not "what way is nearly the fastest?". So anything that's known to be marginally slower is still slower. The lambda probably is how I'd write the first version of the code if I was using filter: I don't claim to be steeped in Python idiom but if anyone here is, it's Tim :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, it's complicated ;-) Relative speed depends not only on loop overhead, but on the "typical expense" of object comparison, which varies according to the object types and values being compared.  In nastier cases, `filter()` with (as @JonClements suggested) `__ne__` can be twice as fast as the listcomp.  I doubt lambda ever wins.  But if the speed of this *really* mattered, I'd be looking for a different data structure.  So I'd write the lambda too ;-)

Comment: Ah, so for performance one might end up writing something like `getattr(itemToExclude, '__ne__', lambda x : x != itemToExclude)` or `getattr(itemToExclude, '__ne__', partial(ne, itemToExclude))`? In cases where the list comprehension doesn't win, I mean.

Comment: I simply used `filter(itemToExclude.__ne__, lst)` in some timing tests, although there are several more obscure ;-) ways to spell that.  It was always at least a little faster than the listcomp. and sometimes more than twice as fast (like excluding a longish list of ints from a longish list of longish lists of ints).

Comment: The obscurity was just to deal with the fact that `int` has no `__ne__` function in Python 2.7.5, so I figured we'd want `__ne__` if available and `operator.ne` if not.

Answer (score 0):

test.py:

```
lst = range(100) * 100
itemToExclude = 1

def do_nothing(lst):
    return lst

def listcomp(lst):
    return [item for item in lst if item != itemToExclude]

def listgenerator(lst):
    return list(item for item in lst if item != itemToExclude)

def remove(lst):
    for i in range(lst.count(itemToExclude)):
        lst.remove(itemToExclude)

def filter_lambda(lst):
    return filter(lambda x: x != itemToExclude, lst)

import operator
import functools

def filter_functools(lst):
    return filter(functools.partial(operator.ne, itemToExclude), lst)

lstcopy = list(lst)
remove(lstcopy)
assert(lstcopy == listcomp(list(lst)))
assert(lstcopy == listgenerator(list(lst)))
assert(lstcopy == filter_lambda(list(lst)))
assert(lstcopy == filter_functools(list(lst)))
```

Results:

```
$ python -mtimeit "import test; test.do_nothing(list(test.lst))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.9 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit "import test; test.listcomp(list(test.lst))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 686 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit "import test; test.listgenerator(list(test.lst))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 737 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit "import test; test.remove(list(test.lst))"
100 loops, best of 3: 8.94 msec per loop

$ python -mtimeit "import test; test.filter_lambda(list(test.lst))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 994 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit "import test; test.filter_functools(list(test.lst))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 815 usec per loop
```

So `remove` loses but the rest are pretty similar: the list comprehension may have the edge over `filter`. Obviously you can do the same thing for an input size, number of removed items, and type of item to remove, that are all more representative of your real intended use.